# Powershell script file not appearing in domain sysvol on all machines

Tags: windows-server-2008, replication, sysvol

I've run into a strange problem that I suspect may be related to DC replication.

We have two DCs, let's called them `domaincontroller1` and `domaincontroller2` for the purpose of this question.

We've put a Powershell file (.ps1 extension) in `\\domain.local\sysvol\domain.local\scripts\Logon`. This is used as a GPO logon script.

On some machines on our domain, the script is working as intended. On others, Event Viewer reports that the file can't be accessed.

If I run `\\domain.local\sysvol\domain.local\scripts\Logon` from my desktop, I can see a load of scripts - but not the PowerShell script in question.

If I run `\\domaincontroller2\sysvol\domain.local\scripts\Logon`, I still can't see the PowerShell script.

**However, if I run `\\domaincontroller1\sysvol\domain.local\scripts\Logon`, I can.**

If I log on to `domaincontroller1` and run `\\domain.local\sysvol\domain.local\scripts\Logon`, I can also see the file.

I've tried running `repadmin /replicate domaincontroller2 domaincontroller1` in case that was the problem, but this says "Sync completed successfully" and still the file doesn't appear.

**[EDIT] Additional information:**

We're using FRS for SYSVOL replication.

Here's an excerpt from today's FRS log (from `DOMAINCONTROLLER1`, the PDC) which may highlight the problem:

```
<SndCsMain:                     5708:   883: S0: 13:46:04> ++ ERROR - EXCEPTION (000006ba) :  WStatus: RPC_S_SERVER_UNAVAILABLE
<SndCsMain:                     5708:   884: S0: 13:46:04> :SR: Cmd 0ba573b0, CxtG 3fdec058, WS RPC_S_SERVER_UNAVAILABLE, To   OLDDOMAINCONTROLLER.domain.local Len:  (364) [SndFail - rpc exception]
<SndCsMain:                     5708:   904: S0: 13:46:04> :SR: Cmd 0ba573b0, CxtG 3fdec058, WS RPC_S_SERVER_UNAVAILABLE, To   OLDDOMAINCONTROLLER.domain.local Len:  (364) [SndFail - Send Penalty]
<FrsHashCalcString:             6048:  5192: S0: 13:46:04> Name = S-1-5-21-201938778-1626411824-782984527-19720
<SERVER_FrsRpcSendCommPkt:      6048:   449: S0: 13:46:04> ++ ERROR - Invalid Partner: AuthClient:DOMAIN\DOMAINCONTROLLER2$, AuthSid:S-1-5-21-201938778-1626411824-782984527-19720
<FrsHashCalcString:             6360:  5192: S0: 13:46:04> Name = S-1-5-21-201938778-1626411824-782984527-19720
<SERVER_FrsRpcSendCommPkt:      6360:   449: S0: 13:46:04> ++ ERROR - Invalid Partner: AuthClient:DOMAIN\DOMAINCONTROLLER2$, AuthSid:S-1-5-21-201938778-1626411824-782984527-19720
<SndCsMain:                     5708:   883: S0: 13:46:25> ++ ERROR - EXCEPTION (000006ba) :  WStatus: RPC_S_SERVER_UNAVAILABLE
<SndCsMain:                     5708:   884: S0: 13:46:25> :SR: Cmd 0ba570b0, CxtG 08968a89, WS RPC_S_SERVER_UNAVAILABLE, To   OLDDOMAINCONTROLLER.domain.local Len:  (364) [SndFail - rpc exception]
<SndCsMain:                     5708:   904: S0: 13:46:25> :SR: Cmd 0ba570b0, CxtG 08968a89, WS RPC_S_SERVER_UNAVAILABLE, To   OLDDOMAINCONTROLLER.domain.local Len:  (364) [SndFail - Send Penalty]
<FrsDsFindComputer:             2204:  9312: S2: 13:48:52> :DS: Computer FQDN is cn=DOMAINCONTROLLER1,ou=domain controllers,dc=domain,dc=local
<FrsDsFindComputer:             2204:  9318: S2: 13:48:52> :DS: Computer's dns name is DOMAINCONTROLLER1.domain.local
<FrsDsFindComputer:             2204:  9332: S2: 13:48:52> :DS: Settings reference is cn=ntds settings,cn=DOMAINCONTROLLER1,cn=servers,cn=default-first-site-name,cn=sites,cn=configuration,dc=domain,dc=local
<SndCsMain:                     5708:   883: S0: 13:49:13> ++ ERROR - EXCEPTION (000006ba) :  WStatus: RPC_S_SERVER_UNAVAILABLE
<SndCsMain:                     5708:   884: S0: 13:49:13> :SR: Cmd 0ba57230, CxtG 08968a89, WS RPC_S_SERVER_UNAVAILABLE, To   OLDDOMAINCONTROLLER.domain.local Len:  (364) [SndFail - rpc exception]
<SndCsMain:                     5708:   904: S0: 13:49:13> :SR: Cmd 0ba57230, CxtG 08968a89, WS RPC_S_SERVER_UNAVAILABLE, To   OLDDOMAINCONTROLLER.domain.local Len:  (364) [SndFail - Send Penalty]
<FrsHashCalcString:             6360:  5192: S0: 13:49:13> Name = S-1-5-21-201938778-1626411824-782984527-19720
<SERVER_FrsRpcSendCommPkt:      6360:   449: S0: 13:49:13> ++ ERROR - Invalid Partner: AuthClient:DOMAIN\DOMAINCONTROLLER2$, AuthSid:S-1-5-21-201938778-1626411824-782984527-19720
```

Our old DC is still being referenced in there (I'm not actually sure if that was ever demoted, or just turned off!) but I think the bigger problem is the line `++ ERROR - Invalid Partner: AuthClient:DOMAIN\DOMAINCONTROLLER2$` - that DC **is** still active and clearly isn't replicating correctly.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are you using FRS? I'm guessing you are if you have Windows Server 2008.

Comment: Yeah Greg, we're still using FRS.

Comment: Is the domain controller where the file exists is the PDC Emulator?

Comment: Yeah, `domaincontroller1`.

Comment: It sounds like you need to troubleshoot SYSVOL replication, specifically looking for an FRS Journal Wrap error in the FRS event log.

Comment: Good idea Joe. I've added some log entries which may be relevant.